# Arc length in polar coordinates: Why isn't $dS=r×d\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

As a sort of exercise, I tried to derive the formula for arc length in polar coordinates, using the following logic:

$$dS = r(\theta)d\theta\\
\implies S=\int r(\theta)d\theta$$

However, it turns out the formula is

$$S = \int \sqrt {r^2+\left(\frac {dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta$$

I could follow the derivation for the correct formula, but why is mine wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Note that $S=\int rd\theta \implies S=r\theta$. It doesn't take into account that the radius changes.

Comment: I made a correction so it says what I was thinking. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Perhaps this picture is helpful! Here is the link to the page: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394888/derivation-of-d-theta-ds-r

Comment: Perhaps this picture is helpful!
Here is the full link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394888/derivation-of-d-theta-ds-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a segment of the curve along a radius from the origin of your polar co-ordinates. That increases the arc length without changing $\theta$ at all and $rd\theta=0$ for this segment. So you need to take into account the radial component.

Answer (score 5):

Your first formula is incorrect. For instance, consider the line $y=x$ and you want to get the length of the line segment from $x=0$ to $x=1$. The length is $\sqrt2$, and the equation in polar coordinates is $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}4$. If we use the first formula, we get the length to be $0$.

In terms of $x$, $y$, we have
$$S = \int \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2} = \int \sqrt{1+y'^2} dx$$
Setting $x=r \cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$, we get
$$dx = dr \cos(t) - r \sin(t)dt$$
and
$$dy = dr \sin(t) + r \cos(t)dt$$
Hence,
$$(dx)^2 + (dy)^2 = (dr)^2 + (rdt)^2$$

Comment: I can understand why this disproves my formula, but I still don't understand where I went wrong in the derivation. The length of an arc is the radius times the angle, so then why wouldn't it work? Thank you for the answer

Comment: I figured out where I went wrong, I was equating the distance between the arc and origin to the radius of curvature

Answer (score 2):

I just realized where I went wrong. The length of an arc is the *radius of curvature* times the angle, not the radial distance between the arc and the origin times the angle. Thanks to all the other answers

Comment: This doesn't invalidate the proposed $ds = r\ d\theta$ entirely. It only means you have to account for $dr$ as well, such that $ds = \sqrt{(r\ d\theta)^2+dr^2}$. Also, please be so kind as to accept an answer, even if your own (I personally think @MarkBennet fully and succintly addressed your question).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting topic.

First to @mathguy, $\int r d\theta = r θ$ is wrong. Because usually $r$ is a function of $\theta$. so $\int r d\theta =\int r(\theta)d\theta$.

The reason why the concept of "*curve length* $r d\theta$" can apply to area intergration in polar coordinates $Area=\int \frac{1}{2} r (r d\theta)$ is that the radial component of the length of the curve doesn't contribute to the area at all, so it is safe to use $r d\theta$ as "*effective curve length*" while the radial component of curve length is completely dropped off in area integration.

Comment: But why it "doesn't contribute to the area at all" ? Why it's "completely dropped off in area integration" ?