# Why can't we use the circumference of a circle to find arc lengths of polar curves?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

To find the area in a polar curve, we use areas of sectors of tiny pie slices to figure out the area, to get
$$A=\int_a^b\frac{1}{2}r^2\,d\theta$$
Why can't we use the circumference of the circle to figure out arc length of a polar curve? I tried and it went something like this:
The arc length of a tiny pie slice is $r\theta$, where theta is in degrees and r is the radius. Adding up all the tiny pie slice arc lengths, we should get
$$\int_a^b r\,d\theta$$
But that is clearly not correct! For example, for $1+cos\theta$, this 'formula' tells us that the arc length is $2\pi$, when the actual arc length is 8. What am I doing wrong? Am I assuming something wrong? Or is it just stupid mistakes?

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason that you can't find the length of a curve $y=f(x)$ by integrating $\int_a^b\mathrm dx$. See also "[Is value of $\pi=4$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/12906/856)"

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{2}r^2 \neq r $, so you should be assuming something wrong.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems: the OP does not think that $\frac{1}{2}r^2=r$. The expression $\frac{1}{2}r^2$ appears in an integral about the *area* bounded by a polar curve; the OP is trying to give an analogous argument for *arc length*, not asserting that $\frac{1}{2}r^2=r$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Completely misread the post. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I disagree with Rahul's comment a little. The real answer to your question is in the accepted answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760757/arc-length-in-polar-coordinates-why-isnt-ds-r×d-theta?rq=1

Comment: The error in the approximation $\delta A\approx \frac{1}{2}r^2\delta\theta$ is second order, while in $\delta s\approx  r\delta \theta$, it is of the same order as the approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_0^{2\pi} r\ d\theta$ will give you the average value of $r\cdot 2\pi$

Arc Length in polar coordinates

In the figure, I have taken a curve in Polar coordinates which I have broken up into pieces.  If we calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} r\ d\theta$ we will get the sum of the dark lines.  It will give you the average value of $r,$ times the range of $\theta$ but it will underestimate the arc length

[image]

If you want the arc length, you are going to need the diagonals. in that figure.

What is the length of the diagonal.  As $d\theta$ becomes small, they are aproximately right triangles with one leg $r\ d\theta$ and the other leg, $dr$

And hypotenuse $\sqrt {(r\ d\theta)^2 + (dr)^2)}$

$\int \sqrt {(r^2 + (\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2} \ d\theta$ will give you the arc length

Comment: How come this minor little differences don't affect the area integral? How come they only affect the arc length, but using area, they can be ignored/dealt with?

Comment: When calculating the areas, we can prove that as $d\theta$ gets small enough $dr$ goes to $0.$  But in the arc length calculation making $d\theta$ very small does not cause $\frac {dr}{d\theta}$ to go to $0$

Answer (score 4):

It is the pythagorean theorem that gives as the arc length for a curve *in any coordinates*.

Consider a small segment ${\rm d}s$ starting from $(r,\theta)$ and going to $(r+{\rm d}r,\theta + {\rm d}\theta)$. As you see in the diagram below the distance due to the angle change is $r {\rm d}\theta$ and the distance due to the radius changing is ${\rm d}r$. Those need to added vectorially to get the displacement of the curve ${\rm d}s$.

[image: pic]