# Finding arc length of colar curve using sectors

Tags: polar-coordinates

For finding the area under a polar curve, we divide the area into small sectors of circles, as shown in image.

[Area of polar curve using sectors](https://images.app.goo.gl/jtAgttTeMFHj6paeA)

Suppose I do the same for finding the arc length.

I divide the curve into small sectors of many circles.

Let dΩ be the small angle subtended by a sector.

Then using the formula of a circumference of a circle,

Circumference = (dΩ/2π)*(2πr)= r*dΩ

And so to find the total arc length between two angles a and b, we take the limit of the sum of the circumferences of the sectors as dΩ tends to 0, which in other words is the integral from a to b of r*dΩ.

But this method is wrong.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: What are you finding, area or arclength?

Comment: If you are finding arclength, look at this answer: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2191190/550450)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we use the circumference of a circle to find arc lengths of polar curves?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191162/why-cant-we-use-the-circumference-of-a-circle-to-find-arc-lengths-of-polar-curv)

Comment: @jeea yes. Thank you very much. Sorry I should have tried more to find a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $ \Omega= \theta $, a symbol more usually used as also in the ma.utaxas.edu link.

When you compute sector area
$$ A= \int \frac12 \cdot r d\theta\cdot r=\int \frac{r^2}2 \cdot  d\theta $$
there is a scope for change of $r$ with $\theta$ as $f(\theta)$

To find infinitesimal arc length you have to use Pythagoras thm at infinitesimal level aka differentials.

$$ ds^2= dr^2 +  ( r\cdot d\theta)^2 $$

$$ s= \int \sqrt{dr^2 +  ( r\cdot d\theta)^2} $$

providing a scope for change of $r$ with $\theta$ here also.